# Short sci-fi story I read in the 1980s: new satellite makes world's computers 'conscious'

Tags: story-identification, artificial-intelligence

I did so much research for so many years, until I found this webpage.

The story starts where the telephones of the whole world ring at the same time after midnight the day after launching a new satellite. The new satellite makes all the computers and ports of the world connected together passing the "consciousness threshold" giving birth to a scary baby that starts playing (by messing up all the control systems of everything in the world).

I researched many short story collections and known authors like Clarke and Asimov and others. Can someone please help me?
Thank you

Comment: duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28110/a-short-story-i-read-long-ago-about-the-phone-system-waking-up

Comment: Was my answer the right one?

Answer (score 24):

This is, of course, the classic "[Dial F for Frankenstein](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?62000)" by Arthur C. Clarke.

> At 0150 Greenwich Mean Time on December 1, 1975, every telephone in
> the world started to ring. A quarter of a billion people picked up
> their receivers to listen for a few seconds with annoyance or
> perplexity

later

> “Now I understand the time delay,” interjected Andrews. “It was
> conceived at midnight, but it wasn’t born until one-fifty this
> morning. The noise that woke us all up was --- its birth cry.”

and at the end

> But he knew already that it was far, far too late. For Homo Sapiens,
> the telephone bell had tolled

Comment: There's also the quite similar 1973 Alfred Bester story, [*Something Up There Likes Me.*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Something_Up_There_Likes_Me)

Comment: @JoeL. - I shall be most surprised if that turns out to be the right answer.

Comment: Just mentioning the striking similarity. I'm sure the Clark story is what the OP is remembering.